# Python NLP - Identify Multiple Choice Questions and Answers

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to NLP. Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

I have documents that contains lots of multiple-choice questions, the choices, and their answers (like the picture below).

[image]

I would like to build a program that is able to get each question, its choices, and the answer. The problem is that not every document follows the exact same format/spacing, so I want to build an all-encompassing program that is able to account for the various formats. Is there anything within NLTK, scikit-learn, or TensorFlow that can help me do this?

Comment: What sort of document? If its pdf, then you need to embed your analysis in the extraction of information from the pdf document, e.g. with pyPDF

Comment: @CLpragmatics - there are both, PDFs and Docx files. I will be using pyPDF for pdfs and python-docx for docx files. I'm more confused about what to do after parsing the files.

Comment: Did you manage to avoid that bug in pyPDF which gives you the parsing output without whitespace? Also, docx is making it even more complicated since Microsoft uses a proper markup. If you want to do it heuristically, this would mean that you first have to gather info on how multiple-choice questions are marked (that is the markup context). supervised machine learning may be a problematic onne since you would need annotated data for training your model. Maybe some unsupervised clustering would work.